# Meteor - Why is the accounts-password package flag as not working on Atmosphere?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, atmosphere.js, meteor-packages

On [Atmospherejs.com](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-password), the `accounts-password` package is flagged as not working. This is what the tooltip says :

> Flagged Package This package has been flagged as not working by the
>   community. Use at your own risk. How does flagging work? Flags are
>   hidden by default. When the number of flags is more than 10% of the
>   downloads per version a warning flag is shown. The flag count is reset
>   every version.

I can't find more info about this on DuckDuckGo. 
Does anyone know when and why it was flagged ?

Comment: That's strange. I created a forum post regarding this, but AFAICT, it worked and still works fine.

Comment: I am also not facing any issue with it, but I prefered to ask :)

Comment: I think a lot people flag it because they thought that means it is important like me before! LOL

Comment: lol, that would be funny. If that happens to be true, we should warn atmospherejs.com about this UX bug